# How to use markdown tags in textarea

Tags: php, markdown, text-editor

How to use markdown tags in textarea. So when If write `**Hello**` and output would be **Hello**.

I want to use markdown tags in textarea where user write post content and publish it.

same like SO editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PHP Library for Markdown

```
composer require michelf/php-markdown
```

Reference: https://github.com/michelf/php-markdown